# What does my supervisor's response mean?

Tags: thesis

For my masters dissertation, we are allowed very few supervisory reviews. In spite of several attempts, only one review materialised, in which the following comments were provided. How am I to interpret this? I went over and beyond the supervisors work and made some suggestions, did that tick him off? Has he read my dissertation? or are these generic comments?

```
Many thanks for this. I’m impressed by how much you have accomplished, 
especially in terms of data collection (although it has not been possible 
for me to independently assess the validity and reliability of your data, 
needless to say.)

If you have the time, I suggest you carefully read the assessment regime 
that applies to assessing your dissertation, and  then rewrite and edit 
until the dissertation clearly meets the criteria set out here, and 
especially the ones related to getting top marks. It would be great to see 
your dissertation get distinction.

I also suggest you spend more time (if you have it) at the outset explaining 
carefully what your main questions/theses are, and then return to these in 
the conclusions and systematically explain how you have answered the 
questions/tested the theses and what your findings are. 

I hope this is useful and wish you the best of luck in completing your 
dissertation. Please do send me a copy of the final version.
```

Comment: What part of this isn't clear? You need to give us a more concrete question. All of the feedback seems fairly straight-forward to me, and absolutely nothing indicates that the person is in any way "ticked off".

Comment: How did your supervisor respond when you asked them this question? (You _did_ ask your supervisor, didn't you?)

Comment: I think the OP is a panicking student reaching the looming deadline that can use a bit of peace of mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Many thanks for this. I’m impressed by how much you have accomplished, 
>   especially in terms of data collection (although it has not been possible 
>   for me to independently assess the validity and reliability of your data, 
>   needless to say.)

He is impressed with your progress, but of course cannot know if you have actually done any mistake. You should consider doing an independent validation of the data. If this is too much, you could do it for part of it, showing that you know how to tackle it.

> If you have the time, I suggest you carefully read the assessment regime 
>   that applies to assessing your dissertation, and  then rewrite and edit 
>   until the dissertation clearly meets the criteria set out here, and 
>   especially the ones related to getting top marks. It would be great to see 
>   your dissertation get distinction.

Some universities have strict rules on how grades are given. For example, mine requires a popular summary at the beginning for passing. If you hand in Nobel prize material without the summary, you will be failed (with apologies from the professor). Verify you fulfil all these requirements.

> I also suggest you spend more time (if you have it) at the outset explaining 
>   carefully what your main questions/theses are, and then return to these in 
>   the conclusions and systematically explain how you have answered the 
>   questions/tested the theses and what your findings are.

Obviously, this part of your thesis is lacking. Maybe related to the previous point.

> I hope this is useful and wish you the best of luck in completing your 
>   dissertation. Please do send me a copy of the final version.

All in all, good job! I think your supervisor is happy.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and thoughtful break-down. I can now focus my efforts on fixing these issues, without imagining a hundred counterfactual scenarios. Honestly, thank you!